# Drupal commerce payment callback endpoint

Tags: commerce

Currently I'm work for a payment gateway plugin, the payment gateway will returning data by using the post method to my Drupal site once the payment transaction occur. I would like to know is that any endpoint and what are the hook is able to handle this process.

Answer (score 0):

so - this sounds like an IPN (instant payment notification), commerce payment does not handle that, so you have to pass the ipn url defined in hook_menu to your gateway in the specific parameter when submitting the _redirect_form, or setting it in your gateway configuration - depends on the gateway ..

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 *
 * adds the callback uri
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // Define an always accessible path to receive IPNs.
  $items['some_uri/IPN/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'your_module_process_ipn',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

so - your ipn looks like this httpx://example.domain/some_uri/IPN/What/ever
maybe that the What/ever is set by the gateway. if nothing is set, adjust the item in hook_menu !

then your callback function does take the action, like:

```
/**
 * Processes an incoming IPN.
 *
 * @param $uri
 *   dynamic URI
 * @param $debug_ipn
 *   Optionally specify an IPN array for debug purposes; if left empty, the IPN
 *     be pulled from the $_POST.
 *
 */
function commerce_postfinance_process_ipn($uri = NULL, $debug_ipn = array()) {
  $ret = 'IPN failed';
  if (ipn_valid($uri, $debug_ipn)) {
    $ret = 'IPN OK';
  }

  print $ret;
  exit(0); // hook_exit will not be invoked !
}
```

and in the ipn_valid function you access the $_POST array.

> don't forget to create a commerce payment transaction if the ipn is
>   OK.

refer the [paypal wps module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_paypal/tree/modules/wps/commerce_paypal_wps.module?id=5f12628) for this (see funciton **commerce_paypal_wps_paypal_ipn_process**)